# Text disappears on hover

Tags: html, css

Please tell me how to make the image enlarge, but the text on the image does not disappear

[without hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPPbR.jpg)
[with hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAnF9.jpg)

HTML

```
<div id="cards" class="container">
            <div class="cards">

                <a href="#" class="card_body">
                        <h3 class="card_body-title" >Lil Peep Type Beats</h3>
                        <img src="/img/lil peep.jpg" class="card_img" alt="">
                </a>

                <a href="#" class="card_body">
                        <h3 class="card_body-title">Juice Wrld Type Beats</h3>
                        <img src="/img/juice.jpg" class="card_img" alt="">
                </a>

                <a href="#"class="card_body">
                    <h3 class="card_body-title">Xxxtentacion Type Beats</h3>
                    <img src="/img/tentacion.jpg" class="card_img" alt="">
                </a>

            </div>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
.cards{
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.card_body{
    position: relative;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 20px; 
    color:antiquewhite;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius:20px;
}

.card_img{
    transition: all 800ms ease-out;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:20px;
}

.card_img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.2);
    display: block;
}

.card_body-title{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 24px;
    left: 10px;
}
```

The problem is that when the image is enlarged, the text that was on it disappears.I think the problem is in the html, with the parents

Please tell me how to make the image enlarge, but the text on the image does not disappear

Comment: put the transform on the anchor (`.card_body`), not the `img`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Z-index property on .card_body-title. it will fix this issue

```css
 .card_body-title {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 24px;
      left: 10px;
      z-index: 2;
  }
```

Comment: i love u so much. 
it turned out to be easier than i thought

Comment: :) my pleasure it help you, by the way thank for love hhehehe